# How do I re-select a range in vim?

Tags: vim

Assume I just yanked some text to another file through:

```
:8,12 w file.txt
```

How can I use the same range without having to enter 8,12 again?
I might want to delete the text afterwards. Currently I use:

```
:8,12d
```

But it seems like needless repetition.
Maybe there's a way to accomplish this in one step?

Note: I understand I could use a Visual Selection and then use the gv command. That's not what I'm looking to answer with the question.

Comment: Indeed question is a duplicate of that one. I searched but couldn't find it. Thank you for pointing it out everyone. For the record, the answer I found most helpful was this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11020580/1253966